# JMESPath - Unable to query a value in a list within another list

Tags: jmespath

Given the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "json": {
       "buildInfo": [
         {
           "first": "James",
           "last": "d"
         },
         {
           "first": "James2",
           "last": "d2"
         }
       ]
     },
     "status": 200
   },
   {
    "json": {
       "buildInfo": [
         {
           "first": "Jacob",
           "last": "e"
         },
         {
           "first": "Jacob2",
           "last": "e2"
         }
       ]
    },
    "status": 200
  }
]
```

I am trying to query the inner list key json.buildInfo."last" for a value to then extract an number of  key value ie json.buildInfo.*."first".    HOwever I am struggling to get this to work.

I can find the data using a flattening operator...

```
[*].json.build[].last[contains(@,`d`)]
```

...but I cannot work out how to perform a query on this that then allows me to obtain extra information list "first" key.   On a json with no inner list on buildInfo, I can do something like

```
[?json.buildInfo.last==`d`].json.buildInfo.first
```

The switch to list of buildInfo items is proving challenging.

Can someone provide me an guidance here?

Thanks

Comment: I just got this to work for the query  [?json.buildInfo[?contains(last,`d2`)]], but then I am not sure how I extract just the one matching block the d2 matches to as the above appears to return the entire buildInfo block containing it which inlcudes the other one also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this works - but not sure I know why...

[?json.buildInfo[?contains(last,'d2')]].json.build_info[]|[?last=='d'].first